# Square each number in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to square each number in an array and my original code didn't work. I looked up another way to do it, but I'd like to know WHY the original code didn't work.

Original code:

```
function(arr) {

    ret= [];            

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        root = Math.sqrt(arr[i]);
        ret.push(root);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Working Code:

```
function(arr) {

    ret= [];

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        ret.push(arr[i] * arr[i]);
    }

    return ret;     
}
```

Comment: Well, *why* didn't it work? (Describe "didn't work".) Note that sqrt is the "square root of", which is different from "the square of". Observing a simple `Math.sqrt(10)` vs `10 * 10` should have indicated exactly what "didn't work".

Comment: Math.sqrt - is square root. See Math.pow

Comment: OP used the word root, so it seems like it was intentional.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Math.sqrt` gives you **square root** not square of a number. Use `Math.pow` with second argument of `2`.

Answer (score 17):

How about that ?

```
function (arr) {
  return arr.map(function (x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  });
}
```

[`Array.map(func)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) applies the function to each element of the map and returns the array composed of the new values.
[`Math.pow(base, exp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) raises `base` to its `exp` power.

Comment: Now it can be: `arr.map(x => Math.pow(x,2))`

Answer (score 4):

The first sample is taking the square root, not squaring the value. To square you want to use

```
Math.pow(arr[i],2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it can be done, using a simple method called `.forEach`

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
numbers.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    array[index] = element* element;
});
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to Square each number in an array in javascript

```
Array.prototype.square = function () {
    var arr1 = [];
    this.map(function (obj) {
        arr1.push(obj * obj);
    });
    return arr1;
}
arr = [1, 6, 7, 9];
console.log(arr.square());
arr1 = [4, 6, 3, 2];
console.log(arr1.square())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function write with **[ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)** **Exponentiation** (`**`):

```js
let arr = [1, 6, 7, 9];
let result = arr.map(x => x ** 2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The original code is taking the square root of the value. The second version is multiplying the value with itself (squaring it). These are inverse operations

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(let squareIt of numbers){
    console.log(Math.pow(squareIt, 2));
}
```

Resolved by [kiss-barnabas](https://www.udemy.com/user/kiss-barnabas/)

Answer (score 0):

Use embedded `for` , for pretty syntax :

```
      var arr=[1,2,3,4] ;
      [for (i of arr) i*i ]; 

      //OUT : > [1,4,9,16]
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, a bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript

Comment: Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Declarative Programming :)

```js
let list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let result = list.map(x => x*x);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unnecessary loops, use `map()`function

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
function square(a){            // function to find square
  return a*a;
}
arrSquare = array.map(square);    //array is the array of numbers and arrSquare will be an array of same length with squares of every number
```

You can make the code shorter like this:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
arrSquare = array.map(function (a){return a*a;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let mapped = arr.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2));
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Do we use Math.pow?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: It's just one of many options for solving this. Of course we can solve it differently :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
let kiss=[3,4,5,6];
let arra=[];
for(o in kiss){
   arra.push(kiss[o]*kiss[o])
  

}
console.log(kiss=arra)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using array square root of the first number is equal to the cube root of the second number

function SquareAndCube(arr) {
    let newarr = [];
    for(i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(Math.sqrt(arr[0])/2 === Math.cbrt(arr[1])/2  ) {
            return true;
       } else return false;
    }
}
console.log(SquareAndCube([36, 215]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the `.map()` method:

```js
const number = [2, 6, 6, 2, 8, 10];
const squareNumber = number.map(num => num*num);
console.log(squareNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function squareDigits(num){
  //may the code be with you
  var output = [];
  var splitNum = num.toString();
   for(var i = 0; i < splitNum.length; i++){
     output.push(splitNum.charAt(i))
    }

   function mapOut(){
    var arr = output;
    return arr.map(function(x){
        console.log(Math.pow(x, 2));
    })
   }
   mapOut();
}

squareDigits(9819);
```

This should work

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. You're squaring each digit of the input, that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @PatrickHund The title clearly shows "Square each number in an array in javascript". I assumed each number to be the digit of the input.

Answer (score -1):

This will work

`const marr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(marr.map((x) => Math.pow(x, 2)));`

Answer (score -1):

```
function map(square,a) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0;i<=a.length-1;i++)
   result[i]=square(a[i]);
  return result;
}

var square = function(x) {
   return x*x;
}

var value=[1,2,3,4];
var final= map(square,value);
console.log(final);
```

You can also try the above code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, edit your answer in order to correct formatting of the code.