# Square values in an array (JavaScript) plus floating point error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, floating-point, square

I am following the first and second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645186/square-each-number-in-an-array-in-javascript). I have subtracted the mean from the value then `console.log()` it to check it out. I then use a `for-loop` to iterate through each value like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    Math.pow(squaredArray[i], 2);
};
```

I am also now getting a floating point error it looks like when I added the `for-loop` to square the values.

What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/L2ggsykq/16/)

Comment: What is your floating point error? Are you doing `y = Math.sqrt(z); x = Math.pow(y, 2);` and finding that `x != z` sometimes?

Comment: `x = Math.pow(myArray[i] - mean)` and finding that there are `0.000000004` errors occassionally.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a floating point error, it just sounds like how floating point arithmetic works (small values are notoriously imprecise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to loop through the values in myArray, square them, and store them in squaredArray.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    squaredArray[i] = Math.pow(myArray[i], 2);
};
```

The "floating point error" was because you were trying to do this:

```
Math.pow(undefined, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of the input, you can protect with exception handling:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    try {
        squaredArray[i] = Math.pow(squaredArray[i], 2);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('input [' + i + '] ' + squareArray[i] + ' caused an exception!');
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Also, your original code was squaring but not doing anything with it, so I took the liberty of assigning the result back to itself.