# Squaring each number in an array with dynamically added inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation of a set of data entered by a user into a form with dynamically added inputs. Thus far I have been able to calculate the sum of the elements in the array, but I cannot figure out how to square each element of the array. I have searched this forum, but trying suggestions from the only applicable result ([Square each number in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645186/square-each-number-in-an-array-in-javascript)) did not seem to work. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$(".calcSD").click(function() {
       $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val().trim() || 0);
        sum += parseInt($(this).val().trim() || 0);
        });
```

Where `.calcSD` is the button the user clicks to perform the calculation. Moreover, the length of the array is given by `var number = arr.sort().filter(Boolean).length;` as the script is intended to filter out any inputs that are left blank.

Also, if it make a difference, inputs are dynamically added to the array via:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
```

So I ask: how would go about determining the square of each element in the resulting array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `pow()` method returns the value of x to the power of y (x^y)

`||` in `parseInt` will use base as `0` if it returns `falsey` value

```js
$(".calcSD").click(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var arr=[];
  $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var squared = Math.pow(parseInt(this.value)||0, 2);
    arr.push(squared);
    sum += squared;
  });
  alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button class="calcSD">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Pretty much worked! I used this instead: `parseInt($(this).val().trim()||0)`. Thanks!

Comment: `$` selector is not makings sense here and it will work without `trim` in all the cases..I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I might not have followed you correctly, but couldn't you just multiply the value by itself as it's pushed to the array?

```
$(".calcSD").click(function() {
       $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        arr.push(($(this).val()*$(this).val()).trim() || 0);
        sum += parseInt($(this).val().trim() || 0);
});
```

Comment: `arr.push(...).trim()` will throw error. Suggest getting value and trim it once and put in variable and check it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I wanted to be able to sum the squares of the elements in the array (as it is a part of calculating the SD) so I did this and it works:

```
var sumXsq = 0;    
for(var i = 0 ; i <= number ; i++) {
    sumXsq += parseInt(arr[i]*arr[i]);
}
```

but not quite as good as Rayon's answer.