# Square Each Number In Array With JavaScript - Why is Only First Number Getting Squared and Returned?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645186/square-each-number-in-an-array-in-javascript), I'm trying to square all elements in an array with JavaScript. But currently my code is only squaring and returning one of the elements in the array:

```
function arrayMadness(a) {

    let squaredA = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        squaredA.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));

        return squaredA;
    }
  }

  console.log(arrayMadness([4,5,6]));
```

This is returning `16`

And I wonder why? Shouldn't the fact that `squaredA.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));` appears within the for-loop mean that all of the elements get pushed into the array?

Shouldn't it be returning `[16, 25, 36]`?

I know that there are other ways of doing this, but I'm trying to get familiar with `Math.pow()` - and I'd like to use `Math.pow()` as other solutions have suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning on the first iteration.
Return must be outside the for loop.

```js
function arrayMadness(a) {

  let squaredA = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    squaredA.push(Math.pow(a[i], 2));
  }

  return squaredA;
}

console.log(arrayMadness([4, 5, 6]));
```

---

You can also use `[4,5,6].map(n=>n**2)`

Comment: @HappyHands31, don't forget to check the alternative ECMAScript 6 version @Rafael added to the answer; `[4,5,6].map(n=>n**2)` it's much cleaner.